# Chrome needs many refresh to take changes in my app code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, webpack

I'm developing a big AngularJS webapp and I'm using Chrome to run and debug it (Version 59.0.3071.115 Official Build 64-bit).

the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option is Checked. The building tool is Webpack and the minified app is like 1.5MB.

Every time I make a change in the code, webpack rebuilds the app. And everytime Chrome doesn't get the changes at first refresh. I need to press Ctrl+F5 like 3/4 times to get the changes. It is so frustrating.

It's only me or it is a common problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure the rebuild has completely finished before you're refreshing? I tend to look at recent changes in an incognito window using `Ctrl + Shift + N`.

Comment: Before the refresh I check if webpack has finished the rebuild. Is it possible that the problem is the --watch option of webpack? The watcher make a virtual rebuild (it rebuilds only the part changed, and not the whole app).

Comment: I honestly don't have much experience configuring webpack but I often find I have problems with caching that Chrome does, hence the incognito tab.